# Is there a command for batch codes to change to another specific window?

Tags: batch-file, window, command

Is it possible to put a command into a batch file that will enter text into a specified window and hit the enter key as if the user was interacting with it?

I know of a handy little exe for command prompt called "keystuff" that is capable of changing windows and inserting text, but i cant find where it has the capability to specify which window to change to since it just utilizes Alt+Tab to change the window.

Comment: Using the SendKeys function of vbscript would be really good for this.

Comment: @SomethingDark Could you elaborate any? Like create a vbscript and call it from the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, sort of -- but not entirely reliably, and not with pure Batch.  You can use the `Wscript.Shell` COM object both for its [`AppActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and [`SendKeys`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156592.aspx) methods.  `AppActivate` will let you change the focus to another window either by its PID or its title.  When focusing by window title, the match is first attempted by full title, then title beginning, then title ending, in that order.  So, for example, if you wanted to send keystrokes to Firefox, you could just `shellObj.AppActivate('Firefox')` (because Firefox tabs end in "Mozilla Firefox").

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to specify what part of the window gets the focus.  If you want to `SendKeys` to the URL bar but the Search bar was last focused before the window was last blurred, then keys get sent to the Search bar.  There's no way around that unless you simulate keyboard navigation (something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to focus the Find-in-page, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> four times to focus the URL bar).  It can get a little messy.

Caveats aside, here's an example Batch + Jscript hybrid script (save it with a .bat extension) demonstrating both the `AppActivate` and the `SendKeys` methods.  See the [`SendKeys` TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156592.aspx) for a cheat sheet of symbols and their meanings (such as `~` sending <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

if "%~2"=="" (
    echo usage: %~nx0 "window title" "keys to send"
    echo See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156592.aspx
    goto :EOF
)

cscript /nologo /e:Jscript "%~f0" "%~1" "%~2"

goto :EOF
@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var osh = WSH.CreateObject('WScript.Shell'),
    args = { title: WSH.Arguments(0), keys: WSH.Arguments(1) };

function type(what) {
    var keys = what.split('{PAUSE}');
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length;) {
        osh.SendKeys(keys[i]);
        if (++i < keys.length) WSH.Sleep(500);
    }
}

osh.AppActivate(args.title);
type(args.keys);
```

Using this script, if you enter

```
scriptname.bat "Firefox" "^f{BS}{PAUSE}{TAB 4}{PAUSE}http://www.google.com~{PAUSE}^f{ESC}"
```

... you'll focus Firefox, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open or focus find-in-page, <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to erase any existing search string, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to the URL bar, navigate to Google, then close the find-in-page footer bar.

See?  I told you.  Messy.  But doable.

Comment: Interesting. So the scriptname.bat code works exactly as you typed it, because i am not familiar with Jscripts. Probably would do me some good to read up a bit though. What does the {pause} do, it appears to be just a separator between commands?

Comment: No, i really dont have any experience with JavaScript, thats why i said it wouldnt hurt me to read up on it, but it looks very similar to VB. I was going to wait until i confirmed your answer tonight before i accepted it, but after reading your link i gotcha. It certainly was very helpful and very explanatory. Thanks a million!

Comment: Is one of the caveats you mentioned being able to switch to a window, but not necessarily enter text in it? If I command it to switch the window to notepad and enter some text, it works. If I tell it to switch to notepad++(a much better option for notepad, not sure if you're familiar with it) it switches to the window, but does not put the text in. Do you know of a more reliable way to accomplish this? I am not limited to batch commands, it could be batch, VB, Java, whatever works on most computers.

Comment: Sending `"^f{ESC}text"` seems to work for N++.  It opens the find dialog, closes it, and then mysteriously, text entry starts behaving.